# Deploying Trading Bots on Google Cloud with Cloud Scheduler

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-platform, cloud, bots

If I have 5 bots for trading and a along with this a script that does some updating on prices using scraping. All these files uses Node js. Now, I was able to deploy all the 6 scripts on digital ocean, but due to 6 scripts running together as 6 different processes the CPU usage in even their most expensive plan became 100%. Then I decided to shift to google cloud. But it turns out with GPU it is hell expensive.
Essentially what I want to do is that run the 6 scripts at 3 distinct times in a day for 10 mins. Other than those particular times the 6 scripts do nothing.
I have set a file named concurrently.js that runs all these scripts using the command concurrently.

Is it possible to run concurrently.js at 3 particular times of the day and then after 10 mins when the job is done, shut down the virtual machine?

Say machine turns on at 12.00pm then the 6 files work for 10 mins and then the machine shuts off at 12.10 pm. And then turns on at say 3.05 pm and so on.

If I can schedule on and off of the VM I can afford google cloud.

I got to know about cron and google cloud scheduler, but they need an App url to schedule tasks. But I don't have an app url because I don't have app only, I just want to run the concurrently.js file present in the virtual machine along with other files, can I do the scheduling?

Any help is highly appreciated!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with Google Cloud. Here the process

1. Cloud Scheduler start your Compute Engine VM
2. At startup, the Compute Engine VM runs a startup script that run your process
3. At the end of the process the VM auto shutdown

So for that you need to

- Call the [Compute Engine start API](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/reference/rest/v1/instances/start)
- Set a [startup script on your VM](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/startupscript)
- [Shutdown the VM automatically](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/nodejs-docs-samples/blob/1b454243d25fb667f0722a72457bbea7cd999d74/functions/scheduleinstance/index.js#L75) at the end of the processing

If you are stuck in one step, let me know, I could narrow my help.

Comment: Thank you so much for you answer! I actually tried Microsoft Azure because I was not able to create an account on Google cloud. I am able to auto run and auto shutdown the virtual machine but I am not able to open the files as processes. Is it possible to do it without using pm2 or forever? I just want to run this command in my virtual machine when it starts "node concurrently.js"

Comment: What is pm2?? In addition, be careful, when you run a startup script, you run it with root context (and permission). Thus some element in the PATH aren't present and you can have difficulties to run some commands. Can you detail more what's not working? Or create a new question for that